# Printing QTableView using render method

Tags: c++, qt, pdf-generation

I am trying to print a table view. To fill a table view I have created my own model. To print table I am doing following:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog printDialog( &printer, 0);
if( QDialog::Accepted == printDialog.exec() ) {

    if( QPrinter::Landscape != printer.orientation() ) {
        printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
    }

    QPoint startPoint = QPoint(20, 20);
    QRegion printRegion = QRegion( 20, 20, printer.paperRect().width(),printer.paperRect().height() );
    for( int i = 0; i < m_tables.size(); ++i ) {
        tableView->render( &printer, startPoint, printRegion, QWidget::DrawChildren );
    }
}
```

The issue is that I am printing into PDF file and there I am able to see only a small part of the table. I thought that changing the *region* parameter could help, but in the fact not. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: By "I am able to see only a small part of the table", you mean it is truncated at the edges, right?

Comment: Right. I was able to see couple of cells and scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution. Would be nice to hear your opinion.

```
PrintTableModel* pTableModel = new PrintTableModel();

QTableView* pTableView = new QTableView;
pTableView->setModel(pTableModel);

int width = 0;
int height = 0;
int columns = pTableModel->columnCount();
int rows = pTableModel->rowCount();

pTableView->resizeColumnsToContents();

for( int i = 0; i < columns; ++i ) {
    width += pTableView->columnWidth(i);
}

for( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
    height += pTableView->rowHeight(i);
}

pTableView->setFixedSize(width, height);
pTableView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
pTableView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

This code helped me. To print the table correctly, you just can perform a *render* call:

```
pTableView->render(printer);
```

Comment: Your solution is good and also explained this(http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/08/24/qt-commercial-support-weekly-25-printing-large-tables-2/). Also in those link explained a way of printing table that not fit (too many columns or rows) to one page.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `void QPrinter::setResolution ( int dpi )` to force a number of widget pixels per printer inches, effectively zooming your widget on the printout.